# How to get icons for tabs in TabPageIndicator

Tags: android

Is there a way to create the `TabPageIndicator` with Tab Icons. Right now its just Text.

I have a requirement where I have to implement the `TabPageIndicator` but with Icons for Tabs instead of just Text.

Any useful links or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Accounts");
    spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Accounts", R.drawable.tab_home));
    Intent inte = new Intent(TabsActivity.this, AccountsActivity.class);
    inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec1.setContent(inte);
```